# Can I do this with 1 query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a simple blog with categories in php.

I want that myblog.com/category.php?id=3 show me this:

```
TITLE of the category 3

// other stuff

ALL POSTS of the category 3
```

So, actually I do 2 queries ( 1 for getting the title and 1 for getting the posts ).

Is there a way to do this with 1 query ?

Comment: Well, you could do something like : SELECT  POSTS, TITLE FROM [your table] WHERE ID = @ID

Comment: is it a relation between `?id=3` and your question?

Comment: there is NOT relation with id=3 :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your database tables, you could something like that

```
SELECT c.title, p.data FROM category c LEFT JOIN post p ON p.category = c.category ORDER BY p.date
```

The category title will be repeated for every post though

Comment: I have 2 tables ( category and post ).
But with your query I can't put the title in the top of the page.

Comment: Actually, you can put the title at the top of the page as outputting HTML can be after the query is run. You could populate an array of objects with the data, write the title, and then use a for loop or iterator to output the results.

Comment: So, on the top of the page I do the query for getting all posts and get category's title; do other stuff; print information about the first post of the query; while loop to get others posts. Is this a correct and common way ?

Comment: I could not say it better than @meewoK. If you have a lot of posts to process, beware of memory.

Comment: So the best ( and probably the common ) way is to do 2 queries ?

Comment: That's what I'd do (2 queries). I your database on the same server as your web server ? If not, 1 query could be a better option due to connection time (you should do some tests, and check mysql [connection flags](http://fr2.php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.real-connect.php) like compress).

Comment: Ok but I want to simplify. So I will use 2 queries :D

Answer (score 0):

If you need all fields from these tables so I think you should use @Damien's way.
If you need only titles you can use following query. In this query the first row is a title of a CATEGORY and next rows are titles of posts.

```
select * from
(
select 0 as ordField, categoris.Category_TITLE as Title from categoris where id =3
union all
select 1 as ordField, POSTS.Post_TITLE as Title from POSTS where category_id=3
) t order by ordField
```